# update nested arrays from flat file

Tags: mongodb

Seems this question is a very popular one, but I haven't found an answer (or at least not one I was able to understand).

I'm having a flat file that I would like to store in Mongo using some nestings. Though it is relatively easy to achieve with an insert and unique content I have the need to update the content on a regular base, so would need to be able to use the update commands also.

My flat file looks as follows :

```
Model,Category,Organisation,CountryCode,CountryWarranty,PeriodCode,PeriodQty
Model1,Category1,Org1,Code1,2Y,201707,1
Model1,Category1,Org1,Code1,2Y,201708,2
Model1,Category1,Org1,Code1,1Y,201709,3
Model1,Category1,Org1,Code2,2Y,201707,7
Model1,Category1,Org1,Code2,2Y,201708,8
Model1,Category1,Org1,Code2,5Y,201709,7
Model1,Category1,Org2,Code3,2Y,201707,5
Model1,Category1,Org2,Code3,4Y,201708,6
Model1,Category1,Org2,Code3,2Y,201709,7
...
Model_n,Category_n,Org_n,Code_n,3Y,201802,20
```

and what I like to achieve is the following :

```
{
"_id": "Model1",
"Model_category": "Category1",
"Product_Sales": [
    {
        "Organisation": "Org1",
        "Country": [
            {
                "Code": "Code1",
                "Guarantee_Years": "2Y",
                "Period": [
                    {"Code": 201707,"Qty": 1}, 
                    {"Code": 201708,"Qty": 2}, 
                    {"Code": 201709,"Qty": 3}
                ]
            }, {
                "Code": "Code2",
                "Guarantee_Years": "2Y",
                "Period": [
                    {"Code": 201707,"Qty": 7},
                    {"Code": 201708,"Qty": 8}, 
                    {"Code": 201709,"Qty": 7}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "Organisation": "Org2",
        "Country": [
            {
                "Code": "Code3",
                "Guarantee_Years": "2Y",
                "Period": [
                    {"Code": 201707,"Qty": 5}, 
                    {"Code": 201708,"Qty": 6}, 
                    {"Code": 201709,"Qty": 7}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Below a snippet of what I tried, note that the syntax is specific to my development environment so I know it is not workable or proper mongo, but it's about the basic idea. Any example using the console will do fine for me

```
concat("{update: "master_Sales",
updates: [
{ 
q:{"_id":", %{_id},""},
u:{$addToSet: {
"Product_Sales.Organisation": "", %{org}, "",
"Product_Sales.Organisation.Country": [
-- more here but have no clue --
]
}}
, upsert: true}
]}"
)
```

Adding my organisations works fine, but as soon as I want to add a second level (nested within an org) it goes wrong.

So in essence I want to be able to add this flat content to my Mongo in a nested array structure, and each time one of the values is changed in the future (say the quantity is updated, or a new country is added) that the line is added / updated so I am not forced to do a full refresh and insert each time a line is modified.

What would be the best approach to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> say the quantity is updated, or a new country is added

You can try below update query in 3.6 mongo version.

For updating Qty for Organisation/Country Code/Period Code - Org1/Code1/201707

```
db.collection.update(
   { },
   { "$set": { "Product_Sales.$[org].Country.$[country].Period.$[period].Qty" : 2 } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "org.organisation": "Org1" }, { "country.Code": "Code1" }, { "period.Code": 201707 } ] }
)
```

For adding new Country to Organisation Org2

```
db.collection.update(
   { },
   { "$push": { "Product_Sales.$[org].Country" :  {"Code": "Code4","Guarantee_Years": "2Y"} } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "org.organisation": "Org2"} ] }
)
```

Can be simplified to

```
db.collection.update(
   { "org.organisation": "Org2"},
   { "$push": { "Product_Sales.$.Country" :  {"Code": "Code4","Guarantee_Years": "2Y"} } }
)
```

Comment: Hi Veeram, Thanks already since this looks like it can head me in the right direction. i do however get following error if I use the second example (country to org) : The dollar ($) prefixed field '$[org]' in 'Product_Sales.$[org]' is not valid for storage. Any idea why?

Comment: Yw. So to use `$[org]` syntax you have to be on 3.6 version. Try the `$` version it will work for below version.

Comment: Yeah, my error. I indeed did not realise I wasn't on 3.6 yet. I'll upgrade and probably it will be ok then.